# Solving a second order linear non-homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$L(y) = y'' - 3y' +2y = e^{\alpha x}$$
So we want.
$$L(y) = L_{CF} + L_{PI}$$
and,
$$L_{CF} = C_{1}e^x + C_{2}e^{2x}$$

If we choose $y_{PI}$ as $Ce^{\alpha x}$ we get,
$$y = Ce^{\alpha x}$$
$$y' = \alpha Ce^{\alpha x}$$
$$y'' = \alpha^2 Ce^{\alpha x}$$

So $L_{PI}$ will equal, $$\frac{e^{\alpha x}}{(\alpha - 2)(\alpha - 1)}$$

However, this isn't true for the case $\alpha = 1,2 $ which i'm unsure on how to tackle, can anyone show me the method for this.

Comment: Homogeneous solution is $y=C_1e^{x}+C_2e^{2x}$. Don't forget the $x$. For $\alpha\in\lbrace 1,2\rbrace$ there is a solution $C_3xe^{\alpha x}$, for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \lbrace 1,2\rbrace$ you have given the solution

Comment: You seem to have confused your constants and your variables. In your formula for $L_{CF}$ you have a function in terms of $\alpha$, but remember that $\alpha$ is just a number. Your homogenous solution should be a function in terms of $x$. Try that, and take another look.

Comment: Choose $Cxe^{\alpha x}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For special solution let $y=Cxe^{\alpha x}$ and with substitution find $C=\dfrac{1}{2\alpha-3}$.

Comment: How do we see this without solving? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why without solving?

Comment: I think he means how do you guess the special solution $y = C x e^{\alpha x}$

Comment: This is a rule. When in these type of equations RHS is $e^{kx}$ and $k$ is one of the characteristic equation roots, then we **assume** that.

Comment: Got it, for some reason I thought I had to make the substitution $(Ax+B)Ce^{\alpha x}$

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. I have split the $y'$ term:

$$\begin{align}
y''-3y'+2y &= y''-2y'-y'+2y \\
&= (y''-2y') - (y'-2y)
\end{align}$$

Now let $y'-2y = u$

Then you have a linear equation:

$$u'-u=e^{\alpha x}$$

Leading to 
$$ue^{-x} =\int e^{ax} e^{-x}\, dx\\
u e^{-x} = \frac{e^{(a-1)x}}{a-1}+C_1$$

Now you have another linear equation, solving gives $y(x)$:
 $$y'-2y = \frac{e^{ax}}{a-1} + C_1e^x$$

Comment: Thanks for this type of solution ive never thought of looking at it this way.

Comment: You're welcome!